# Regression trees used for analysis

Tags: tree, regression

Is it common to use regression trees for analytical purposes and not for prediction?  I'd like to use a easily interpretable method to show how various variables and their combinations relate to a continuous variable.  I'm not interested in predicting future values of the continuous variable.  Regression trees seem like a easy way to present how various combinations of variables explain a response variable.  If I'm not predicting, is it necessary to validate the model using train and test datasets?  Are the r-squared and cross validation errors sufficient to validate the model?

Comment: Can you more clarify your question? `If I'm not predicting, is it necessary to validate the model using train and test datasets?`

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I want to use regressions trees for explanatory purposes not for prediction.  Regression trees are a nice intuitive way to present relationships between predictors and a response variable.  I realize I should model the data using regression trees and basic regression and in this case model using test and train data.  I can compare the sum of the square errors for both the regression and the regression tree to evaluate the fits of both models.